# DataGridView Add TextBox & And Allow Edit After Binding

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have one `DataGridView` named **dgv**.

`dgv` is pretty much a plain gridview. No bounded data. No columns added. It's basically empty.

I also have one `DataTable` named **dt**.

I add rows and columns manually into dt.

```
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TexBox", GetType(String)))
dr = dt.NewRow()
dr("TextBox") = String.Empty
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

I then simply set `dgv` datasource into `dt`.

```
dgv.DataSource = dt
dgv.Refresh()
```

I then set the value for this particular cell.

```
dgv.Item(0,0).Value = "xxx"
```

Now when I run and execute all those commands. I happen to retrieve the gridview with that value indeed. **The "xxx" cell appeared and currently it's uneditable**.

What I want to achieve is:
Allow this "xxx" cell to be **editable**. Preferrably if it can be inserted into a `TextBox` control inside the cell.

I googled and researched by myself on doing this. Yet I couldn't find a correct resource.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simulate your code and the following works perfectly :

```
Private Sub LoadData()
        Try

            Dim dt As New DataTable

            'Be carefull here because you right it TexBox instead TextBox  
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TextBox", GetType(String)))

            Dim dr = dt.NewRow()
            dr("TextBox") = String.Empty
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)

            dgv.DataSource = dt
            dgv.Refresh()
            dgv.ReadOnly = False
            dgv.Columns(0).ReadOnly = False
            dgv.Item(0, 0).Value = "xxx"

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

By Default when you edit a cell in a datagridview a textbox will popup on cell,
so no need to make your own textbox
(If you please, Don't forget to marke my answer as **Right** one)